# Can't set Logo in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I've seriously tried everything. 
I've tried both `setLogo()` and `setIcon()`.

I've tried adding `android:logo=""` in manifest.

I've made sure to try both supportActionBar and regular ActionBar. (I'm running sdk 21 with a min sdk of 15.)

The funny thing is if I try to use the regular ActionBar I get null pointers but when I use the support ActionBar it at least works.

Is there anything else I can try...? Here's where I try and change it.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setLogo(R.drawable.logo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your min sdk is 15, i'm not sure why you're using the support package at all.

You class should instead extend `Activity`, and use `getActionBar()`.

Comment: See that's what I thought as well. And I have tried that. I get null pointers  on my ActionBar when I do that though.
I'm using android studio so my gradle files say min sdk is 15 and target is 21. The phone I'm testing on is running 4.4 so I believe that's 18-19. I get the null pointer when I try to access the ActionBar. ab.setLogo() <-- gives me null

Comment: So....wow. I'm so angry/happy right now. 
All I had to do was set in my styles that I was using the android:Theme. 
I was using just Theme. Gah I'm dumb. Thanks!